# Static Image to Use as Thumbnail from Google v3 Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-gridview

I am populating a gridview of locations that I would like to be "snapshots" of the google v3 map.  When a user clicks on the cell of the grid, I want to then open an interactive map in a webview.  Any idea how I get the static images to populate gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/). It gives a static image (with some basic overlays). You can then link the image to your full map.

Comment: I thought this was going to be deprecated in 2013...am I confusing this with the Javascript V2 API?

Comment: No - only the maps api v2 is deprecated. Static maps is still a supported api.